# rigidBody2D.MovePosition not found in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity.While i am following the video tutorial  of  "Catch Game".. I am using the unity 4.3.3 version.

here is my code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BasketController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera cam;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if (cam == null) 
        {
            cam = Camera.main;      
        }
    }

    // Update is called once physics TimeStep  
    void FixedUpdate () {
        Vector3 rawPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3 (rawPosition.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        rigidbody2D.MovePosition (targetPosition);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D' does not contain a definition for `MovePosition' and no extension method `MovePosition' of type `UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Kindly correct my error.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

You need to have Unity 4.5 or newer to use Rigidbody2D.MovePosition:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/cannot-figure-out-my-error.253139/

As workaround you could probably use:

```
rigidbody2D.position = targetPosition;
```

Comment: Thanks for comment.. Are you sure that unity 4.3.3 have not function of "MovePosition"??

Comment: According to Unity's Scriptin API's history it was added in 4.5: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/40_history.html
You get that error message if your unity version is missing that function or if you don't have right using clauses in your C# file.

Comment: I can confirm that in unity 4.3.4 there is no rigidbody2d.MovePosition.